# Export Workflow 2.4

Tags: features, importing-exporting, workflows

I'm trying to export the [workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) configuration from a site using Workflow 7.x-2.4 but the state names and transitions are not well exported.
I'm exporting some strongarm and workflow variables but when I try to install a site using [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features), something is wrong and I get the states without name.

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?